# How to map ManyToOne or OneToMany in Entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

I use Entity Framework for the first time and my question is:

How do you mapping ManyToOne or OneToMany  , as with hibernate in java, with Entity because in the examples I do not really understand ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't exactly understand what your problem is.  Could you include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following Student and Standard entity.

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

In the above example, Student entity includes navigation property Standard and Standard entity includes collection property for Student. This is the default convention to form one-to-many relationship.

Take a look at this link http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Hope this will help

Comment: OK thanks . a last information when once you have built the class , how you doing to instantiate the object from a sql query ?

Comment: Query like this for `var result = context.Standards
    .Where(u => u.StandardId == 2)
    .SelectMany(u => u.Students)
    .OrderBy(p => p.StudentId)
    .Take(10);`  for first 10 standards which `StandardId = 2` and result will be order by all connected students `StudentId`